# how to clear some characters by regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re, sys
m = re.sub('(','',m)
```

**i want to clear "(",")" .
what shoud i do ?**

Comment: Is this an html file? What do you eventually want to do with it? Extract smth?

Comment: yes , it's an html file .

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for something this simple; use translate:

[Python string doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
>>> str = "This is a (string) (example)..."
>>> str.translate(None, "()")
'This is a string example...'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = re.compile(r'<a>.*?</a>')
my_source = p.sub('<a></a>', my_source, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: If you’re not doing anything with `m`, you don’t need the callback, do you?

Comment: @minitech: do you mean, print p.sub('<a></a>', my_source, re.DOTALL) ? oh, yes, it works.